# How do I tell Jenkins not to use -current- but instead use a service account for running deployment pipelines?

Tags: jenkins, credentials

Below is an image of the creds error I see in the configuration settings for all of my pipelines, until I go in and manually select the correct creds to use, which is a service account.

For some reason, I can't get it to default to the service account.  It uses 'current' which is an old defunct UID for a closed out account.

I can't find any setting or anything that would fix this. Unless the problem is in my master seed script or the child scripts it calls when generating the scripts? I don't see anything there unless I just don't know what to look for.

[image: Current incorrect configuruation]

Comment: this question would probably be better for stack overflow or devops, see https://meta.superuser.com/questions/13805/should-we-do-something-about-the-high-number-of-jenkins-questions-with-no-votes

Answer (score 0):

If you use Job DSL to create your pipeline jobs, you can set the credentials as:

```
scm {
        git {
            remote {
                github('account/repo', 'ssh')
                credentials('github-ci-key')
            }
        }
    }
```

See https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/pipelineJob-definition-cpsScm-scm-git